# How to change the keyboard for alphanumeric password on lock screen on iPod

Tags: keyboard, ipod-touch, language

I want to change the keyboard of my passcode to Japanese. Even if I change the language of my iPod to Japanese and get rid of the English keyboard, I still only can set my passcode in English. I can't find anything that will help me do this. If any of you know please help! Arigato!

Answer (score -1):

**Good morning!** report it to Apple support 
Request them to investigate, ask them to inform you and also post "how to" on their website as well

Note: Usually Apple or other smartphones makes only post the most common situations or most common inquiry's answers

For those more specific questions, one has to ask them to investigate and post it 
If there is an Apple support agent or technical support person that knows how to use his or her resources and is willing to investigate on it for more than 5 minutes, they may be able to get you an answer

**Thanks!**

Comment: This question was asked several months ago so it might not be morning there anymore.  Please edit your answer to include the steps ("how to") for making the change the OP requested.  If you don't know them, it's not a very good answer to tell them to ask Apple how to do it.  See [answer] for info on how to answer questions.